# How to check all elements in a <ul> list using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, list, selenium, webdriver

Is it possible to loop through all the `li` elements of the `<ul> </ul>`. Let's say I have an unknown number of `li` elements, so one way to loop through them would be to impose a `for` loop with a maximum possible number of `li`s, say 100, and impose `try and catch`.

```
try{
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='...']/ul/li[i]"));
}
}
catch {...}
```

However, it does not recognize the `i` index? How can I make it recognize it?

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Webdriver has `findElements` API, which can be used for this purpose..

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='...']/ul/li")); 

for (WebElement element: allElements) {
      System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='...']/ul/li"));
int s=allElements.size();
for(int i=1;i<=s;i++){
    allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='...']/ul/li"));
    allElements.get(i).click();
}
```

Use this

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

Your purpose is to get all li within a ul. So it needs to locate ul first then all li in that ul. You can do by using the following Selenium Java code:

```
WebElement ul_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='list-unstyled']"));
        List<WebElement> li_All = ul_element.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        System.out.println(li_All.size());
        for(int i = 0; i < li_All.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(li_All.get(i).getText());
        }
        //OR
        for(WebElement element : li_All){
            System.out.println(element.getText());
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your initial code might work if you put the index `i` out of the string like so:

```
try {
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='...']/ul/li["+i+"]"));
    }
}
catch {...}
```

Comment: You have limit the i value as i < 100. If the number of li s is more than 100, what will happen? As the number of li s is unknown, it's unwise to set the value as 100